# Table layout span issue in android

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

I am using below xml file to draw a add details form.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:background="@color/body_background"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="2dp">

    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/no_image" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="@string/medicine_name" />
        <EditText
            style="@style/textbox"
            android:id="@+id/txtMedicine"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="@string/treatment_for" />
        <EditText
            style="@style/textbox" 
            android:id="@+id/txtTreatmentfor"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="@string/side_effects" />
        <EditText 
            style="@style/textbox"
            android:id="@+id/txtSideEffects" 
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="@string/price" />
        <EditText 
            style="@style/textbox"
            android:id="@+id/txtPrice" 
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="@string/storage_specifivation" />
        <EditText 
            style="@style/textbox"
            android:id="@+id/txtStorageSpecification" 
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView android:text="@string/general_information" />
        <EditText 
            style="@style/textbox"
            android:id="@+id/txtGeneralInformation" 
            android:inputType="text"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="@string/submit" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

I am getting output :

[image]

But I want image view spanning with two columns and same button also fit with the complete with.

I want to output like in the below form

[image]

What I am missing or what is the issue in xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `weightSum` in `TableRow` and `layout_weight` in ImageView and Button like...

ImageView :

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/product_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/no_image"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>
```

Button :

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:text="dfghdgd"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>
```